# why is IMUL producing wrong result after a particular number is increased

Tags: assembly, x86-64

```
.section .data
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
pushq $3  
pushq $2
call power

addq $16 , %rsp
pushq %rax

pushq $3
pushq $5  ##if i change this value anything above 3 , the result produced is wrong
call power

addq $16 , %rsp
popq %rbx

addq %rax , %rbx

movq $1 , %rax
int $0x80

power:
pushq %rbp 
mov %rsp , %rbp 
subq $8 , %rsp
movq 16(%rbp) , %rbx
movq 24(%rbp) , %rcx
movq %rbx , -8(%rbp)

power_loop:
cmpq $1 , %rcx
je end_power
movq -8(%rbp) , %rax
imulq %rbx , %rax
movq %rax , -8(%rbp)
decq %rcx
jmp power_loop

end_power:
movq -8(%rbp) , %rax
movq %rbp , %rsp
popq %rbp
ret
```

in attached code if i change the highlighted pushq $3 with anything above 3 , the result produced is wrong , for eg. it produces 133 for 2^3 + 5^3  ,  but if the input 2^3 + 5^4 the result is 121 .

i think it has something to do with IMUL instruction

note: this is power function code from book programming from ground up this code simply tries to explain the stack .

Comment: 121 is the 8 lowest bits of the correct result, I guess you obtained that value by looking at the exit code of the program rather than inspecting `rbx` directly with a debugger